# Targetting elements loaded with jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am doing a website where all internal links make the current page fade out and the new contents fade in. I do that with jquery load(). The loading and fading part works fine like this:

```
    var $mainContent = $("#ajaxcontainer"),
        $internalLinks = $(".internal"),
        URL = '',
        $ajaxSpinner = $("#loader"),
        $el;

    $internalLinks.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
        }).on('click', function() {

            $el = $(this);

            URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
            URL = URL + " #container";

            $mainContent.fadeOut(500, function() {

                $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
                $mainContent.load(URL, function() {
                    $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut( function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(1000);
                    });         
                });

            });


        });
```

As you can see, I am targetting all internal links by a class I've given them (.internal). My problem is that once content gets loaded with ajax, I am not able to target this new content with my jquery, and so the $internalLinks.each() and so on gets broken, meaning that the site just reverts back to the default link behavior.

Another thing which is related to this, is that I want to be able to target this newly loaded content with the jquery.masonry plugin. That also isn't possible the way I'm doing things now.
Thank you very much.

Comment: After calling `.load` you need to call `$internalLinks = (".internal");` again so that jQuery can re-scan the DOM for the new elements.

Comment: Or `$mainContent.find('.internal').on('click', function(){});` would work too

Comment: [Check out this similar post][1] reinitializing the plugin is what you need


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321292/reinitialize-other-javascript-functions-after-loading-a-page-with-ajax-paginatio?rq=1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I tried recalling $internalLinks = (".internal"); which isn't working, but maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. I put it as the callback to the load? That didn't do anything. Your other suggestion I think I'm going to have to ask you to elaborate on? Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: I would advise you to push URIs to browser history so that users may still use forward / back functionality with AJAX-loaded pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the page, the old `.internal` links are removed, so the event handler attached to them won't work. Change your code to use event delegation:

```
$('.internal').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
}); 

$(document).on('click', '.internal', function() {

        $el = $(this);

        URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
        URL = URL + " #container";

        $mainContent.fadeOut(500, function() {

            $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
            $mainContent.load(URL, function() {
                $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut( function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(1000);
                });
                $('.internal').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
                });        
            });

        });
});
```

As you see, I refresh the attribute `href` of each link after a refresh, too.

** EDITED ** I was missing changing the `href` attribute the first time. Now it should work!

Comment: Your solution isn't quite working for me. My links just behave like normal links now, no ajaxing. I am running the entire code inside a $(document).ready(function() is that correct?

Comment: There was a little typo in my code. I missed a `.` in `$('.internal').each(...`. I've corrected it. Try again, please.

Comment: yes I noticed that; It didn't do the trick though... not working for me. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Ah, wait, I think I saw what's the problem!