# JQuery UI animate() doesn't work after AJAX load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, load, jquery-animate

I have a button that changes color when hover over and out using JQuery UI's animate(). That button loads a page with AJAX when clicked on. The thing is that once I click that button, the animate() doesn't seem to work, it just freezes in one color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Jquerytest</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="lib/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   $('document').ready(function() {

    var menubutton_animation = 200;
    $('.menubutton').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({ color: "#D1571F" }, menubutton_animation);
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({ color: "#000000" }, menubutton_animation);
    });

    $('.menubutton').click(function(){
        $('#targetframe').load('portfolio.html');
    });

  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Portfolio" id="portfolio">
  <div id="targetframe"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The styles.css contains this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Comfortaa';
 src: url('Comfortaa.eot'), 
        url('Comfortaa.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
.menubutton {
    height:40px;
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:Comfortaa;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there any error shown in developer console, after clicking the button?

Comment: Just this XMLHttpRequest error: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. I don't think it's related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load ajax-generated markup it will not retain the functionality it had before. Just put it on a function a call it when you add content :

```
<script>
   function load_animation(){
     var menubutton_animation = 200;
     $('.menubutton').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({ color: "#D1571F" }, menubutton_animation);
     }, function(){
        $(this).animate({ color: "#000000" }, menubutton_animation);
     });
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
     load_animation();

     $('.menubutton').click(function(){
        $('#targetframe').load('portfolio.html');
        load_animation();
     });
  });
  </script>
```

should "refresh" the jquery after you load new content.

Comment: By the way a quick search lead me to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321292/reinitialize-other-javascript-functions-after-loading-a-page-with-ajax-paginatio

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code and didn't work. I also read that other post and couldn't find the reason why this initialization function doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: yup i think i know :) the right syntax is : $( document ).ready(function() {

Comment: I'm really sorry, the previous code worked perfectly. My bad. Thank you!